# Apexcharts - How to convert 1 000 to 1K yaxis label

Tags: apexcharts

Can use costume format?  My charts work with $ dates:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var downloaded = [28683,62977,94111,146146,177601,200647,205921];
var viewTitle = '{if $currentLocale == 'en_US'}Example{else}Example{/if}';
var downloadTitle = 'Example';
var labelconvert = function(value) {
var val = Math.abs(value); if (val >= 1000) { val = (val / 100) + " K";} return val;};
var options= {
  chart:{
     toolbar:{show:!1},
     height:200,
     type:"area",
series:[{name:viewTitle,data:viewed},{name:downloadTitle,data:downloaded},],
yaxis:{show:1,labels:{formatter:labelconvert,},title:{text:xTitile,style:{fontSize:'12px',fontWeight:'bold',fontFamily:'Roboto',color:'#113060'}}},
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Please make it easier for us to help you by editing your question: Format the code as JavaScript for highlighting and add line breaks to avoid horizontal scrolling.
What is the result of your attempted solution?

Answer (score 10):

```js
yaxis: {
  labels: {
    formatter: function(value) {
      var val = Math.abs(value)
      if (val >= 1000) {
        val = (val / 1000).toFixed(0) + ' K'
      }
      return val
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, formatter working.  But necessary fix small numbers. Try add .toFixed(0) after "return val" this work on small numbers < 0 and stop render chart if val numbers  >=1000. Сan toFixed and formul work together?

Answer (score 0):

```
yAxis: [
            {
                type: 'value',
                position: 'left',
                axisLabel: {
                    formatter: function (value) {
                        let val: string | number = Math.abs(value);

                        if (val >= 10 ** 3 && val < 10 ** 6) {
                            val = (val / 1000).toFixed(0) + ' K'
                        } else if (val >= 10 ** 6) {
                            val = (val / 1000000).toFixed(0) + ' M'
                        } else {
                            val = val;
                        }

                        return val
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Hi. This is code is for the echats yaxis label formatting. Suppose you have a number that is way large in that condition you can short them. For example 1000 can be written as 1k and 100000 as 1m (k  = thousand) and (m= million). I hope, I answered your question @Tyler2P

Comment: vikram bhai i am new to all this, can you help me how to call this function